# Android - OkHttp 3.6.0 Adress.class Duplication

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I've come across similar issues which indicates the same problem. However, in my case it seems to be happening in a different way which shouldn't produce this issue as described below:

Imagine I have two internal private libraries, published on private maven repository named as below:

```
com.x.y.analytics
com.x.y.player
```

Both of these libraries use OkHttp 3.6.0 with the given code snippet below:

```
provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

So basically, I don't include the actual library when I'm releasing an aar to maven, I compile this and provide it to mentioned libraries from the parent project with the code snippet below:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

However, even though everything should be fine due that there is only 1 compiled version of this library, I have the error given below:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':application:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: okhttp3/Address.class

I believe this issue would happen if I used compile to inject the library inside the private libraries but since I use provided could you elaborate the issue if there are any leads to a fix?

PS: There is also an issue for GitHub project of OkHttp which can be found [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3166).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. And I tried to add this line

```
android {
configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
}
```

And It works fine for me. Please try to do it.